# Stop App From Running In Background

Tags: android, background, app-store, android-mediaplayer

I need to ask a quick question now I am writting an app that should be able to stream a shoutcast station that is all done.

What I need to do now is don't allow the app to run in the background when stop is clicked at the moment it just stops the music but I need it to also stop running from the background without exiting the app as it is a stop music button.

I need this since I am using tele phony manager to detect incomming calls etc to stop the music while the user is in a call

```
package com.beanie.samples.streaming;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import com.beanie.samples.streaming.R;
import com.beanie.samples.streaming.MyService;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

;



public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
      private static final String TAG = "MyServices";

    private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://195.154.237.162:8936/";

    private static final String START_STICKY = null;
      Button buttonPlay, buttonStopPlay;



      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {

          android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
          // This above line close correctly
      }








      public void ring()
                {
       Bundle savedInstanceState = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
          // register PhoneStateListener 
            PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {


           public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
               {


                 // If phone ringing
           if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                    {
               stopPlaying();                                        
                       }
               // If incoming call received or making a call
                  if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
                      {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Music will keep playing after your call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      stopPlaying();

                         }


                  if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
                       {
                     startPlaying();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Music Will Now Keep Playing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                   }
                       };
             telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);







                }




      public void unregister_ring()
                {


       Bundle savedInstanceState = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
          // register PhoneStateListener 
            PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {


           public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
               {



                   }
                       };
             telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);







                }





        /** Called when the activity is first created.
         * Keep this here all the application will stop working */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ring();
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            initializeUIElements();

            initializeMediaPlayer();

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
            buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);

            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);


        }





    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;





    private MediaPlayer player;

    private InputStream recordingStream;

    private RecorderThread recorderThread;

    private boolean isRecording = false;







    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);


    }




    public void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();



            }
        });

    }







    private void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

         playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Buffering ", percent).show();


          Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
    }











    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {

         startPlaying();









  player.setLooping(false); // Set looping










        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
            stopPlaying();
            unregister_ring();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }








    private void stopPlaying() {

            player.pause();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();


        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        stopRecording();
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void startRecording() {

        BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(RADIO_STATION_URL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            final String FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + "Songs";

            File folder = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(FOLDER_PATH
                    + File.separator + "sample.mp3")));
            recordingStream = connection.getInputStream();

            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while (recordingStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1 && isRecording) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                writer.flush();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                recordingStream.close();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {

        try {
            isRecording = false;
            if (recordingStream != null) {
                recordingStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class RecorderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRecording = true;
            startRecording();
        }

    };
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you play the musicstream from a Service? That way you could interact with the service and make it stop, without stopping the app.

Comment: I posted the code i'm using  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); but that just closes the whole app as will.

Comment: What is going wrong exactly? You seem to be calling stopPlaying when the phone is ringing.

Slightly offtopic: Some ways to improve your code:
1) Use a switch-statement for TelephonyManager's state
2) You're setting the contentView 3 times and calling super.onCreate() twice.. No need for that!

Comment: Thanks Remember I am only a few days new to java and android so I think i'm doing well so far what I want is once I press stop then stop the app from running in the background so it doesen't use tele phony manager but dont exit the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop using the TelephonyManager you can 'unregister' the listener:

```
telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

This way there's no need to kill the app.

See the [documentation of TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29). Also [www.developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) is a great place to learn more and to see documentation.

Comment: Ok Thanks alot for this! ;)
You have headed me in the right direction I have accepted your answer 

Also the only problem in the future if I add more features that needed to be killed would i just add those to the buttonStopPlay?

aswill if it works good I like to code it right as will as I will make mistakes but guess it's all about learning

Thanks Again!